# How to rename CSV headers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to merge these records into an existing CSV file. However, the two files have headers that are named differently. How can I cleanly and efficiently rename the CSV headers so that the match the file I'm merging to?

Comment: Do you mean the first line of the csv? If so they are like every other line. When you use the csv library to read a csv file you'll get an array of values for each line. If the column ordering is the same you could just delete the first line of the first csv before merging into the other.

Comment: Yes, I mean the first line. The column orders are not the same so I'm hoping to simply turn every how into a hash and merge the records that way. I was hoping that CSV#header_convert might be of assistance? However, I can't find any examples of this in use and the documentation is a little confusing.

Comment: http://technicalpickles.com/posts/parsing-csv-with-ruby/ this might help you. Looks like CSV#headers gives you an array of CSV::Row with headers. Then you can map over the rows and call #to_hash on them to get the hashes you want. `CSV.new(csv).headers.map(&:to_hash)` something like that

Comment: I'm able to use `CSV.read('data.csv', headers: true).headers.map(...)` to get an array of modified headers, but how do I then run a foreach on the CSV data and use these headers instead of the ones that are in data.csv?

Comment: A CSV file will only have a single header row a the top, so the file you are merging to already has the correct headers.  Just ignore the headers in the file you are merging from.

Comment: That would work if the order of the columns can be relied upon to be consistent but I am trying to build this in a way that I can disregard the order of the columns and simply rely on the headers, like so:

`CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  results << row.to_hash
end`

Comment: If you got it working, you should answer your own question :p.

Comment: I don't have it working. I'm still wondering how I can run a foreach on a CSV file but rename the headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

```
CSV::HeaderConverters[:map_to_main] = lambda do |header|
  # work your magic here
  header
end
CSV.open(file,
  headers: true,
  header_converters: :map_to_main).to_a.map(&:to_hash)
```